# PHP SimpleXML repeated data

Tags: php, xml, foreach, simplexml

Using SimpleXML to pull data from a basic XML file.  The XML looks something like:

```
<shop>
  <section>
    <title></title>
    <products>
      <item>
        ...
      </item>
    </products>
  </section>
</shop>
```

I can load and loop out the  nodes, but when I populate the HTML with each sections items it keeps repeating the first sections items.  I'm confused because each section name is outputting correctly but using the first set of items.

```
foreach($xml->section as $section){
$i=0;
echo '<div class="section"><div class="sectionTop"><h3>'.$section->title.'</h3><a class="expand">+/-</a></div>';         

foreach($xml->section->products as $products){
    foreach($products->item as $item){
        if($i==3){echo '</div><div class="extra">';}?>

        <div class="item">
        <img src="<?=$item->image?>" />
        <div class="prodName"><?=$item->name?></div>
            <div class="price">&pound;<?=$item->price?></div>
        <a href="<?=$item->url?>" class="shopNow">SHOP</a>
    </div>

        <? 
        $i++;
        unset($item);
    }
    unset($products);
}
```

Can anybody help?  This where I am so far, unset doesn't work :(  `<shop>` is `$xml`

Comment: unsetting the loop variable within the loop is completely unnecessary. If you're really worried about the memory usage of hanging on to those variables (which you shouldn't be), then at least unset them *after* the loop.

Comment: can the products element contain more than 1 item element? e.g <products><item>...</item><item>..</item></products>

Comment: Yes, products contains up to 9 items, each with their own nodes (name,image,url,price).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use $section variable to count it products.

So
foreach($xml->section->products as $products){
->
foreach($section->products as $products){

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure I understand?!

Comment: Sorry, I got it working and then immediately realised this is exactly what you said!  Works perfectly now, and better than that, I understand why it was going wrong - so thank you very much :)